# how to solve BadParcelableException problem

Tags: android

the code can not run in android 13 of Pixel4 , but it can run in other phone.

```
            Intent share_intent = new Intent();
            share_intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share_intent.setType("video/*");
            share_intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,fileUri);
            final PackageManager pm = m_activity.getPackageManager();
            List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = pm.queryIntentActivities(share_intent, 0);
            List<LabeledIntent> intentList = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i = 0; i < resInfo.size(); i++) {
                ResolveInfo ri = resInfo.get(i);
                String packageName = ri.activityInfo.packageName;
                final Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.setType("video/*");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileUri);
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "ttt00");
                CharSequence title = "123";
                intentList.add(new LabeledIntent(intent, packageName, title, ri.getIconResource()));
            }

            Intent openInChooser = Intent.createChooser(intentList.remove(0), "Share");
            openInChooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentList.toArray(new Parcelable[intentList.size()]));

            m_activity.startActivityForResult(openInChooser,GameActivity.ActivityRequestCode.SHARE_VIDEO);
```

it will throw the exception

```
2022-05-26 20:22:35.144 1685-3668/? E/PackageManager: Package Manager Unexpected Exception
    android.os.BadParcelableException: Parcel data not fully consumed, unread size: 40
        at android.os.Parcel.enforceNoDataAvail(Parcel.java:929)
        at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub.onTransact(IPackageManager.java:2216)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService$IPackageManagerImpl.onTransact(PackageManagerService.java:7086)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1280)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1244)
2022-05-26 20:22:35.146 29790-29790/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: android:ui, PID: 29790
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{android/com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity}: android.os.BadParcelableException: Parcel data not fully consumed, unread size: 40
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3679)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3816)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:99)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2299)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7844)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
```

PS:

what is `It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.` , but i have no details to say , this is all, but why i cant post...

for the exception do you have the same quest? who can help me please?

Comment: Do not use a wildcard MIME type with `ACTION_SEND` (you have `video/*`). Use the actual MIME type of the content. Beyond that, make sure that what you named `fileUri` is actually a `Uri` with a `content` scheme, such as from `FileProvider`, and add `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` to each of your `Intent` objects.

Answer (score 0):

Use @Parcelize to gracefully read and write data from and into parcels.
Without this, you need to be extremely careful of the sequence in which you write and read data. They should be exactly the same. Otherwise, data is overwritten, or in the worst case, corrupted. @Parcelize does this work for you under the hood.
https://developer.android.com/kotlin/parcelize

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same issue because of using `LabeledIntent` on some Oppo devices running Android 13. Not using `LabeledIntent` fixes the issue on those devices.